# View logs of shutdowns? [Vista]

Tags: windows-vista, windows-event-log

I'm a normal user with Windows Vista Professional. How do I check the previous date and time when my computer is shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this in the event viewer:

1. Go to start, type in Eventvwr.msc in the run box
2. Expand Windows Logs, then click on system
3. Order the records by date (they will likely all ready be ordered by date)
4. Look for Event ID 6006
5. Open the event, look at the time.
6. profit!